# Login failed for user 'sa'. error

Tags: sql, database-connection

I got an error, and I didn't find the solution.

Description:

> An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "mcommon"
>   requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'sa'.

My SQL string:

```
PACKET SIZE=4096;USER ID=sa;PASSWORD=**hidden**;
DATA SOURCE=localhost;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=False;
INITIAL CATALOG=mcommon;CONNECTION TIMEOUT=60;
```

I think my SQL string is correct, because I can connect another server with this string. My SQL user information is true – I can connect with SQL Management Studio.

Please help me.

Comment: it was not my real pass but thanks

Comment: Are you sure, you have database mcommon?

Comment: Did you install the database `mcommon` on your local machine as well?  Also, `localhost` doesn't look like a valid `DATA SOURCE`.  If you intend to access the local machine, you may need to give the named instance, such as `MACHINE-NAME\SQLEXPRESS`, depending on the version on SQL Server you have installed on the local machine.

Comment: i am sure. i have a db name of 'mcommon'

Answer (score 0):

Whether you think it or not, your connection string isn't correct. My suggestion would be that the `Data Source` is incorrect, but it really is impossible to tell.

One thing is certain, though. You should **not** be using the `sa` account in your application.